# Unable to share html2canvas converted image through whatsapp api

Tags: javascript, php, html

Unable to share html2canvas generated image to whatsapp api

I was trying to convert html to an image using html2canvas and I have a base64 image string which was generated through canvas.toDataURL('image/png') . Now I want this image to be shared through whatsapp as https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=image.png. But my image is not getting passed through the API

```
function share_image()
{
   var data ='';
   html2canvas([document.getElementById('main_div')], {
   onrendered: function(canvas) {
    data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var whatsapp_url = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text='+encodeURIComponent(data); 
    window.location.href = whatsapp_url;
   },
 });    
}
```

---

```
<div id="main_div">
  <span onclick="share_image()">
  </span>
</div>
```

When i click on the span, i want to generate an image of the div and share it through whatsapp from web

Comment: The "send" api does not seem to support sending images. It's just a basic "click to chat" api. https://blog.cloudrail.com/whatsapp-api-how-to-use-the-whatsapp-chat-api/ - https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251

Comment: You may eventually try with one of "non official" library on github : https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=whatsapp+api&type=