# How to use html2canvas and then share the image generated on whatsapp?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, html2canvas

I am trying to use html2canvas to generate a snapshot of an html card(which by the way is working properly and the image also gets downloaded properly when I test it on PC) but I need to pass this image to the shareViaWhatsapp function.
Not sure which variable stores the generated image so I can pass it directly as the third parameter in  this.socialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp("Come join ABCD with me","Subject", **imageURL**) instead of **imageURL** .

When I run the apk on phone, I get "URL_NOT_SUPPORTED" error. Please help.

```
html2canvas(this.screen.nativeElement, {
      imageTimeout: 15000, //newline
      scale:3, //newline
      useCORS: true
      }).then(canvas => {
        imageURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = imageURL;
        a.download = "letter.jpg";
        a.click();  
        this.socialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp("Come join ABCD Community with me","Subject", imageURL)
        .then((entries) => {
          console.log('success ' + JSON.stringify(entries));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert('error 1' + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what is unclear about the message “*URL_NOT_SUPPORTED*”? It’s pretty clear that sharing data URLs to WhatsApp via this mechanism is, well, not supported.

Comment: Nothing exactly unclear, just looking for a way to pass this generated image as an argument to the shareViaWhatsapp function, the image parameter expects a string, but even "letter.jpg" gives the exact same error

Comment: I'm basically looking for the variable which holds the generated image so I can pass it to shareViaWhatsapp directly

Comment: There are a couple comments in this post that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55397861/12914833